# .click() not working to change background image w/jQuery

Tags: jquery, events, onclick, click

```
$(function(){
$('.change-bg').hover(function(){
    $('header').css({ 'background-image' : 'url("img/map.jpg")' });
}, function(){
    $(this).fadeTo('slow', 1);
});
});
```

This is a rudimentary jQuery script I'm using. The version above works, however, when I change `.hover()` to `.click()` (on line 2), the script no longer works.

What I'd like is for the background image to change onClick. Help?

Comment: Be careful of using words that are globally namespaced.  Using `header` as a class or id could potentially conflict in code, depending on it's usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the following line:

```
$('.change-bg').hover(function(){
```

To

```
$(document).delegate('.change-bg', 'click', function(){
```

Or

```
$(document).on('click', '.change-bg', function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this line

```
 $('header').css({ 'background-image' : 'url("img/map.jpg")' });
```

I guess you are missing either a # or a . in the selector

It should be some thing like this'

```
$('#header').css({ 'background-image' : 'url("img/map.jpg")' });
```

or

```
$('.header').css({ 'background-image' : 'url("img/map.jpg")' });
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to bind the click event this way:

```
$(function(){
$('.change-bg').bind('click', function(){
    $('header').css({ 'background-image' : 'url("img/map.jpg")' });
}, function(){
    $(this).fadeTo('slow', 1);
});
});
```